# Logstash > Skip grokked matches

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

This is the logstash config for apache access_log:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/http.log"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
  }
}
```

I would like to collect all fields except of **%{WORD:method}**

How can I let the field be skipped/ignored from beeing transfered to ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by removing the word "method" which appears after WORD. So your grok filter would look like:

```
 match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
  }
```

The words which appear after the colon are variable names, where the types like IP, WORD, NUMBER, etc. are stored and passed on.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the Mutate block on your grok filter.

[plugins-filters-mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_tag)